# Child .NET applications running under earlier versions of Framework (Pools are setup)

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

I have an interesting situation where I am deploying an application to a subdirectory that is running an earlier version of the .NET framework that the root application.

```
/   <- .NET 4.0
/child/   <- .NET 2.0
```

The application pools are setup correctly, as far as I can tell.  The error page I received for the child app indicates the framework to be:

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4216; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4209
```

That looks good to me.  However, I get this error:

```
Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
```

This seems to indicate that the web.config file on the root application is overwriting part of the child web.config file.  Is there something I can do to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future people running into this problem, you can wrap  in your configuration file with this:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

Remember to add  after  and you'll be good to go.